# Encontrar números en un texto en xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, app, split

Estoy haciendo una app en xamarin que tiene que leer textos de ésta, extraer todos los números y sumarlos, el problema está en cómo puedo extraer los números de la variable sms y guardarlos en una variable para al final sumarlo todo, este es el código:

```
using Mensajeria;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Mensajeria 
{

    public class datos
    {
        public string num { get; set; }
        public string sms { get; set; }
    }
}
public class men
{
    public List<datos> mens { get; set; }
    public men()
    {
        mens = new List<datos>();
        Load();
    }
    public void Load()
    {
        mens.Add(new datos
        {
            num = "232843874",
            sms = "aldkajsldkaj 2535335 ñadalksdñka",
        });
        mens.Add(new datos
        {
            num = "3123122",
            sms = "skjdlaskdj 78778 laslajsldj"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podés definir "números"? ¿Puede hacer negativos? ¿Decimales? ¿Exponente? ¿Imaginarios? ¿Infinitos?

Answer (score 3):

**Método #1**

Puede usar lo siguiente para la extracción de los número en un string:

```
string valorResultante = new String(sms.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

---

**Método #2**

Un poco mas largo es:

Haciendo uso de la expresión regular `\d+` para números enteros:

```
 string valorResultante = string.Join(string.Empty, 
                    Regex.Matches(sms.Text, @"\d+").OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value));
```

> Agregue la referencia: `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`.

**Resultado Obtenido**

**Con ambos métodos se pueden obtener los mismo resultados:**

> - Para esto: `sms = "aldkajsldkaj 2535335 ñadalksdñka"` el resultado sería: `2535335`
> - Para esto: `sms = "skjdlaskdj 78778 laslajsldj"` el resultado sería: `78778`
>
> **Nota:** Para admitir números negativos puede usar la expresión regular: `@"-?\d+"`

Espero le sea de ayuda!.